# Lemma 1.2.2. Diamond's Modular Forms

Tags: proof-explanation, modular-forms

The following is from Diamond's Modular Forms book:

[image]

I don't understand the first three lines after the lemma, at all. Also, from which part of the lemma it is *a consequence*? I don't see a connection between the three mentioned lines ("One consequence of the lemma ...") and no part of the lemma!

Simple clear explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a consequence of part $c$. In short, if you write a matrix $\gamma$ in terms of the two generating matrices $T, S$, perhaps as $\gamma = S T S$, then weak modularity for $S$ and $T$ implies weak modularity for $\gamma$.

You can see this by noting that
$$ [\gamma]_k = [S]_k [T]_k [S]_k,$$
so that
$$ [\gamma]_k f = [S]_k [T]_k ([S]_k f) = [S]_k ([T]_k f) = [S]_k f = f,$$
where for each of the three right equalities we use that $f$ is invariant under the slash operator for the two generating matrices.